# UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat pausing in between two animations

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I want to achieve the continuous pulse effect just like in ECG (Heart beat monitor). Currently I'm using two animation blocks.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0f delay: 0.0f options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat  | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone | UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration
                 animations:^{ [image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,70)];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(-320,200,320,70)];}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone | UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration
                 animations:^{ [image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320,200,320,70)];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,70)];}];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This animation dose repeat after its completion, but it takes a little pause before staring again.. I want to remove that pause in between and achieve a continuous and smooth animation..

[image: In case I'm not clear to you, i want to achieve this kind of effect..]

Any hep would be much appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Just so you know i've also tried UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut.. but it still pauses..

Comment: first comment: setAnimationCurve:   "This method does nothing if called from outside of an animation block."

Comment: second: commitAnimations is unused if no beginAnimations:context: is called

Comment: @meronix: I added setAnimationCurve: method just to try out. But it wasn't animating smoothly before I added that method.

Comment: isn't the pause you talk about just the deceleration at the end of each animation? tried to add UIViewAnimationCurveLinear?

Comment: @meronix : thanx for your rply.. but it still takes a pause in between two animations.. Even with UIViewAnimationCurveLinear..  I tried your code too, but no luck..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found out... I used below code to achieve smooth and non-pausing animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{ [image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,70)];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{ [image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320,200,320,70)];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

The important change was I had to replace **UIViewAnimationCurveLinear** with **UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear**.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me, with no pause.

you are changing just the position, no size, so may be better to change the center instead of the frame

```
float originalX = image1.center.x;
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0f delay: 0.0f options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat  | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction                         
          animations:^{ image1.center = CGPointMake(originalX + 320, image1.center.y);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

you don't really need to set the original position in completion block, the "repeat" option does that for you